# Django syndication, how to replace root element

Tags: python, xml, django, syndication

Say I generate rss page using django's built-in syndication framework.

```
<channel xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">
<title>laike9m's blog</title>
<link>http://example.com/blog/rss</link>
<description>Update on laike9m blog's articles.</description>
<atom:link rel="self" href="http://example.com/blog/rss/"/>
<language>en-us</language>
...
```

I want to change the content of `<language>` tag, how do I do it?

I tried define custom feed:

```
class ExtendedRssFeed(Rss201rev2Feed):

    def add_root_elements(self, handler):
        super(ExtendedRssFeed, self).add_root_elements(handler)
        handler.addQuickElement('language', 'zh-CN')
```

It doesn't replace but add another `<language>` tag.

```
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
<channel xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">
<title>laike9m's blog</title>
<link>http://example.com/blog/rss</link>
<description>Update on laike9m blog's articles.</description>
<atom:link rel="self" href="http://example.com/blog/rss/"/>
<language>en-us</language>
<language>zh-CN</language>
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do this by overriding `__init__` for my Feed like so:

```
from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed
from django.utils.feedgenerator import Rss201rev2Feed

class ItunesFeed(Rss201rev2Feed):

    def __init__(self, title, link, description, language=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__init__(title, link, description, language='zh-CN', *args, **kwargs)


class PodcastFeed(Feed):
    feed_type = ItunesFeed
```